# Curl download website like a web browser

Tags: curl

Having some trouble downloading a website using cUrl.

The website in question: cell. com

For now it follows all redirects, e.g:

```
curl -L http://cell. com -o test.html -v
```

...however the file created by cUrl is totally different than what my browser is able to pull out.

Would appreciate help on how to recreate browser's behaviour using cUrl.

Comment: This should get the html of your target page and write it to `test.html`. What are you getting instead?

Comment: I'm getting empty page with some script tags, instead of the real page contains.

Comment: curl doesn't understand javascript. maybe phantomjs would suit your needs better?

Comment: Have you seen that javascript? I don't see any which would make a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.

That website in question plays around with cookies and then on that behaviour redirects to another page which has another Javascript redirect.

Anyway, solution was to use CookieJar and write that cookie to a file:

```
curl -L http://cell. com -o test.html -c cookie_filename
```

Hope that helps for anyone coming here in the future.